# Solving a particular Integer Programming Problem

Tags: integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Integer Programming formulation described as follows:

Assume a set of variable $V$ = ${v_1,...,v_m}$.

The set of total $S$ constraints is of the form:

$$v_1 + \overline{v_2} + v_3 \leq 1    \\
   ...  \\   
  \overline{v_2} + v_4 + v_6 \leq 1 $$

each called a clause, $C$.

> Problem formulation (Objective function):
>
> Find an assignment that satisfies maximum constraints (out of S constraints).

Formally:
$$r(C) = max \sum_{C \in S} z_{C}$$

The variable $z_C$ will be 1 if the each corresponding constraint is true; for example in case $v_1 + \overline{v_2} + v_3 \leq 1$ is true and 0 otherwise.

I'm new to Integer programming and first tool that I tried [MIP solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt) I can write all $S$ constraints easily. But I have no idea how to encode the **objective function**.

Comment: Note that you can replace any appearance of $\overline{v_u}$ with $1-v_u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function to be maximized is $\sum_{C\in S} z_C$.  You can define it [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt#objective).

Comment: You can represent the "such that" part by [defining constraints](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt#constraints).

Comment: No problem.  I recommend working through that complete example and modifying it.